# Crystal Reports JDBC not connecting

Tags: crystal-reports, driver, installation, crystal-reports-2008

I am running crystal reports 2008, and oracle11g. I have tested the connection in SQL developer and i can connect just fine.
However if i try and create a new JDBC connection in Crystal Reports i get ther error

> Failed to Open the connection.
>
> Details: JDBC driver not found.

I have the following set up:

- Oracle Home: C:\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_2\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar
- path: C:\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_2\bin; + hell of a lot more
- I've added C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\4.0\java/lib/external/ojdbc6.jar;$ to the classpath in the CRConfig.xml file.

Why can i not create a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I have a windows 7 64 bit machine, with the 64 Bit crystal and 64 bit Oracle. The 64bit oracle does not interact very well with crystal. The issues were resolved once i installed the 32 bit version of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem using steps as follows:

1. copy the jar file to "external" folder.
2. add the jar to the classpath in the CRConfig.xml.
3. most importantly, I amend the "JavaDir" in the CRConfig.xml to refer to my current java/bin folder, where on my case, it was as follows:
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin